# Printing Image in C#, colors more opaque than printing from OS

Tags: c#, .net, printing, gdi+, system.drawing

I'm trying to print a JPG image from a winforms application, I need the colors to be really close to the original image but the resulting colors are more opaque comparing them to the image printed with the OS (from windows photo viewer or word).

This is the code:

```
private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.PageUnit = GraphicsUnit.Pixel;
        e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
        e.Graphics.PixelOffsetMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
        e.Graphics.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
        //e.Graphics.TextRenderingHint = System.Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.AntiAliasGridFit;
        e.Graphics.CompositingQuality = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.CompositingQuality.GammaCorrected;
        e.Graphics.CompositingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.CompositingMode.SourceCopy;
        var img = Image.FromFile(@"C:\photo.jpg", true);
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(img, 0, 0);
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var result = printDialog1.ShowDialog();
        if (result == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            printDocument1.PrinterSettings = printDialog1.PrinterSettings;
            printDocument1.Print();
        }
    }
```

I've tried with different values for the graphics properties (SmoothingMode, PixelOffsetMode, ...) but I cannot get the real colors. For example black is more like grey when printed by the application, but printed with word is really close to black.

I cannot send the complete photo, but this is a section of the JPG with the same properties:

[image]

Comment: Is the printer in Draft Mode when the colors are faded?

Comment: No, in both tests i'm using the best configuration, and the one I'm printing from Word prints ok, the other doesn't

Comment: switch off Gamma correction

Comment: Are you talking about CompositingQuality? I've tried with: Default, GammaCorrected and HighQuality and get the same result.

Comment: I have a similar issue with a .Net 2.0 program.  I'd love it if someone had some insight into this.  The Windows picture previewer and MSPaint both print the image with full saturation but when printed by my program it appears faded.  I don't believe we are doing anything unusual with the image, we just send it to the graphics context to be printed.  I do wonder if it has something to do with color profiles and if .Net uses a color profile for display on screen which leads to faded colors when printing.